# laptop can't connect to wifi

Tags: drivers, wireless, internet

I can't connect to the internet with wifi but I can connect through Ethernet. I think it has to do with the wireless adapter and the installed drivers. After typing `lshw -C network` I get the following:

```
*-network                 
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: Intel Corporation
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:3b:00.0
       logical name: wlp59s0
       version: 1a
       serial: 50:eb:71:25:32:da
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: bus_master cap_list ethernet physical
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=5.4.0-59-generic firmware=48.4fa0041f.0 cc-a0-48.ucode latency=0 link=no multicast=yes
       resources: irq:16 memory:ed400000-ed403fff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: 1
       logical name: enx503eaa2f7302
       serial: 50:3e:aa:2f:73:02
       size: 100Mbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       capabilities: ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8152 driverversion=v1.10.11 duplex=full ip=192.168.1.2 link=yes multicast=yes port=MII speed=100Mbit/s
```

I am on a Dell XPS with ubuntu 18.04. Can someone help me debug the problem? I am not that knowledgeable of Linux systems.

edit: It is on a dual boot with windows. This `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list` prints the following:

```
3b:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:2723] (rev 1a)
    Subsystem: Bigfoot Networks, Inc. Device [1a56:1654]
    Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
    Kernel modules: iwlwifi
3c:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTS525A PCI Express Card Reader [10ec:525a] (rev 01)
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list` terminal command. Could you connect before? Is it a dual boot with windows?

Comment: @Pilot6 Added the info you requested. I could connect before but it broke. I am not sure when it broke exactly since I am mainly using an ethernet connection.